# Does $X_{n,i}-Y_{n,i} \rightarrow_{a.s.} 0$ imply $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_{n,i}- \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n Y_{n,i}\rightarrow_{a.s.}0 $

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables, almost-everywhere

**Notation**: $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, consider the real-valued random variables
$$
X_{n,1}, X_{n,2}, X_{n,3}, ..., X_{n,n}
$$
We can picture them as  a sort of "infinite triangle''
$$
A\equiv 
\begin{cases}
X_{1,1}\\
X_{2,1} & X_{2.2}\\
X_{3,1} & X_{3,2} & X_{3,3}\\
X_{4,1} & X_{4,2} & X_{4,3} & X_{4,4}\\
...\\
\end{cases}
$$

$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, consider the real-valued random variables
$$
Y_{n,1}, Y_{n,2}, Y_{n,3}, ..., Y_{n,n}
$$
We can picture them as  a sort of "infinite triangle''
$$
B\equiv \begin{cases}
Y_{1,1}\\
Y_{2,1} & Y_{2.2}\\
Y_{3,1} & Y_{3,2} & Y_{3,3}\\
Y_{4,1} & Y_{4,2} & Y_{4,3} & Y_{4,4}\\
...\\
\end{cases}
$$

---

**Assumption 1**: all the random variables in $A$ are i.i.d.; all the random variables in $B$ are i.i.d.

**Assumption 2**: $\forall i\in \mathbb{N}$
$$
X_{n,i}-Y_{n,i}\rightarrow_{a.s.} 0 \hspace{1cm}\text{ as $n\rightarrow \infty$}
$$

---

**Question**: are Assumptions 1,2 sufficient to claim
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_{n,i}- \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n Y_{n,i}\rightarrow_{a.s.}0 \text{ as $n\rightarrow \infty$}
$$
If not, which other conditions would be sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that expectations are finite. If all the $X_{n,i}$ are all i.i.d. (even when $n$ increases), then $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_{n,i}\to \mathbb{E}[X_{1,1}]$ by the strong law of large numbers. Similarly, $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n Y_{n,i}\to \mathbb{E}[Y_{1,1}]$ and therefore
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_{n,i} - \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n Y_{n,i} \to \mathbb{E}[X_{1,1}] - \mathbb{E}[Y_{1,1}]
$$
almost surely.
It remains to understand whether the hypothesis  "$X_{n,i}-Y_{n,i}\to 0$ almost surely" implies that  $\mathbb{E}[X_{1,1}] = \mathbb{E}[Y_{1,1}]$ but this is true because the $X_{n,i}$'s are i.i.d. (to see this, for instance, observe that almost sure convergence implies converge in distribution and since the $X_{n,i}$'s are i.i.d.
$ \mathbf{1}_{\{t\ge 0\}} = \lim_{n} P(X_{n,1} -Y_{n,1} \le t) = P(X_{1,1} -Y_{1,1} \le t) $, which gives  $\mathbb{E}[X_{1,1} - Y_{1,1}] = 0$).